# Java 8 CompletableFuture future is waiting needlessly for other futures

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have this simple code below. All futures should start at the same time. `future13` is supposed to run right after futures 1 and 3 finish, but in the logs I see that it waits until after futures 1, 2, 3, and 4 all finish. Why does it wait for futures 2 and 4?

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.junit.Test;


public class Test1 {

    private void loop(Long id, int max) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                System.out.println(id);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> createConfigFuture(Long id) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            loop(id, 100);
            return null;
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = createConfigFuture(1L);
        CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = createConfigFuture(2L);
        CompletableFuture<Void> future3 = createConfigFuture(3L);
        CompletableFuture<Void> future4 = createConfigFuture(4L);

        try {
            CompletableFuture<Void> future13 = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future3)
                .thenApply(v -> {
                    loop(999L, 5);
                    return null;
                });
            CompletableFuture<Void> mainFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(future13, future2, future4);
            mainFuture.get();

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does `future13` always finish after `future2` and `future4` or it also starts after? Since `future13` takes more time and `CompletableFuture.allOf` doesn't make any guarantee about the order what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wonder if it is a simple case of futures 1-4 finishing at almost the same time (they al have the same run time and about the same start time) and the check mechanism behind the CompletableFuture is just to slow to distinguise

Comment: I second the thought that while using the print statements you might just not be able to distinguish between which one is getting executed first. All the *future1, 2, 3 and 4* are asynchronously executed and that is where the *future13* which is though waiting for 1 and 3 to complete normally, still looks like have completed after 2 and 4 as well.

Comment: Since you don't specify an `Executor`, it is using the common `ForkJoinPool`. It would thus be useful to indicate its size (or the number of CPU cores, if you didn't specify the size). On my computer (4 cores, common pool thus having a size of 3), `future13` is processed at the same time as `future4` and finishes first.

Answer (score 1):

There is a queue to get an execution slot in the JRE's default fork-join `Executor` which all async tasks will serialize on.

The task `#2` is ahead of the task `#3` in that `Executor` queue, so before you observe the execution of the task `#3` (and, respectively, of the completion task `#13`) the `#2` should get its execution slot first.

This may be seen as `#3` linked to `#2`, but other than that there should not be any additional coupling between the tasks.

Comment: Since `future13` is created with `thenApply()` (and not `thenApplyAsync()`), it does not need a slot: its task will be run immediately by the same thread when the latest of `future1` and `future3` completes (or by the main thread if `thenApply()` is called after both are already completed).

Comment: @DidierL - you are absolutely correct. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok so I sshould stay with `thenApply()` not `thenApplyAsync()`, then do I have a warranty that `mainFuture.get()` will return / finished after all futures (including future13) finishes?

Comment: When you need full control - I would use the Async and in addition pass it an executor to use explicitly. You will then be able to switch to sync processing (if needed) by simply using a `Runnable::run` method reference as an executor. This way the processing graph stays unchanged and only the “execution policy” changes.